# Can this query be solved using something besides 2 CTEs?

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression, window-functions

I’m writing a query against a table of fictional insurance clams called CLAIMS, using RANDOMLY GENERATED FICTIONAL NAMES AND DATA.

There are 5 distinct categories in the column called PRIMARY_DX:
Alcoholism, Anxiety Disorder, Depression, Psychosis, Substance Use Disorder

The other main columns are PATIENT_ID and CLAIM_PAID_AMT

I want to sum up the CLAIM_PAID_AMT per PATIENT per PRIMARY_DX and list only the top 5 patients who have the highest sum per PRIMARY_DX

The only way I could think to do this was with two Common Table Expressions, where in CTE1 I partition by PRIMARY_DX and PATIENT_ID and SUM the CLAIM_PAID_AMT for each PATIENT.

Then in CTE2 I use a ROW_NUMBER function on CTE1, to partition by PRIMARY_DX and sort by the TotalClaims DESC and select the top 5 from each PRIMARY_DX.

I’ve been writing SQL for less than 2 years and was wondering if this could be accomplished in one CTE or perhaps with some form of Cross Apply?

I’m including my code and the output below.

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
select PRIMARY_DX, PATIENT_ID, TotalClaims = SUM(CLAIM_PAID_AMT)
OVER (PARTITION BY PRIMARY_DX, PATIENT_ID ORDER BY PATIENT_ID, CLAIM_PAID_AMT DESC)
from claims
)
, 
CTE2 AS
(SELECT *, RowCounter = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRIMARY_DX ORDER BY TotalClaims DESC) FROM CTE1)
select CTE2.PRIMARY_DX, CTE2.TotalClaims from CTE2
where RowCounter <= 5
order by CTE2.PRIMARY_DX, CTE2.TotalClaims DESC
```

Alcoholism  3737.51 Joe Smith

Alcoholism  3282.07 Suzie Homemaker

Alcoholism  3207.72 Joey Strummer

Alcoholism  3040.52 Rusty Nailfile

Alcoholism  2997.02 Big Ben

Anxiety Disorder    3291.14 Norman Pigsty

Anxiety Disorder    3113.05 Billy Bob

Anxiety Disorder    3101.13 Rachel Antarctica

Anxiety Disorder    3058.52 John John

Anxiety Disorder    3021.98 Kathy Europa

Depression  3466.14 Freda Beagallly

Depression  3279.25 Ron Jeremize

Depression  3140.43 Sharon Sharonaz

Depression  3119.26 Allie Kat

Depression  3118.54 Biff Biffstoferson

Psychosis   3098.13 James Monopoly

Psychosis   2991.23 Leon Erroneously

Psychosis   2857.69 Lucie Ratched-McMurphy

Psychosis   2678.88 Billy Bibbitz

Psychosis   2602.24 Sam Zypperzsky

Substance Use Disorder  3435.27 Donald Duckaronawitz

Substance Use Disorder  3300.33 Mickey Mousetrap

Substance Use Disorder  3285.41 Hector Heathercoatz

Substance Use Disorder  3179    Erin GoBragh

Substance Use Disorder  3147.09 Bono Edgerstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need one sub-query or CTE since you can use the aggregate within the `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Here is an approach using the sub-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT PRIMARY_DX, PATIENT, SUM(CLAIM_PAID_AMT) AS CLAIM_PAID_AMT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRIMARY_DX ORDER BY SUM(CLAIM_PAID_AMT) DESC) AS RowId
    FROM Claims GROUP BY PRIMARY_DX, PATIENT
) T
WHERE RowId <= 5
```

And if you prefer CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT PRIMARY_DX, PATIENT, SUM(CLAIM_PAID_AMT) AS CLAIM_PAID_AMT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRIMARY_DX ORDER BY SUM(CLAIM_PAID_AMT) DESC) AS RowId
    FROM Claims GROUP BY PRIMARY_DX, PATIENT
) SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowId <= 5
```